remove _id inside schema mongoose
If there is an external schema and not an internal schema, can I delete the ID of this schema? Any plan without an ID, is that possible?
I need to remove from the schema and not save in database
#mongoose
#express
const planSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
description: String
}, { _id: false });

can you please elaborate more?

could you maybe explain why do you want a schema with no id?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
